remove nan from column of lists
I have a dataframe with a column of empty value and list with values which includes 'nan'. I need to remove the nan and create another column with total count of values within list in each cell.
data = {'Value_count': [0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0],
    'Risk Rating': [nan, '[No Risk, nan]', '[Medium, No Risk/Not Rated]', '[High, nan]', '[Medium, No Risk, nan]', '', nan]}

I have tried the below code first to convert the empty strings to empty list and then tried to remove the nans
df['Risk Rating'] = df['Risk Rating'].apply(lambda x: [] if pd.isna(x) or x == '' else x)

def remove_nan_from_list(lst):
    return [item for item in lst if not pd.isna(item)]

df['Risk Rating'] = df['ListColumn'].apply(remove_nan_from_list)

but its coming up list of list of strings like [['N', 'o', '', 'R', 'i', 's', 'k']]
Apologies for not providing detailed result as this is done for official work

Actually, I can't reproduce your error, your code works fine. Are you sure you're using the correct column? This should be df['Risk Rating'].apply(...)

Without apply: df['Risk Rating'] = [[x for x in lst if not pd.isna(x)] for lst in df['Risk Rating']]

I am not getting the result as expected, getting nested lists in the output, just a heads up, I have done a transformation in the column, as the original columns had some values within the list and remaining are empty, so i converted the empty values to empty lists for iterative purpose.

It looks like you could have strings instead of lists. Maybe use [item for item in lst if not pd.isna(item)] if isinstance(lst, list) else lst

Try to run your code with your example and see for yourself. I believe you do have an error, but please provide a [mre] that reproduces it.

There is a slight change in the values of Risk Ratings, these are strings of lists

Then you have a issue since your string representation is not valid. '[High, nan]' should have been '["High", nan]' or '["High", "nan"]'

You provided data, doesn’t generate a DataFrame it will show an Error message. NameError: name 'nan' is not defined

please use np.nan instead of nan

I have tried to work something based on your description of the problem and the sample data provided. You could try to use the ast library to evaluate the strings containing Python literals. However, the sample data still has some issues that would require some changes in order to do that. So assuming that you can modify the sample data to be something like:
data = {'Value_count': [0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0],
        'Risk Rating': [np.nan, '["No Risk", "nan"]', '["Medium", "No Risk/Not Rated"]', '["High", "nan"]', '["Medium", "No Risk", "nan"]', '', np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

you could do the following. First convert the empty strings to np.nan
df['Risk Rating'] = df['Risk Rating'].replace('', np.nan)

Then, convert the string representation of lists to actual lists using the ast.literal_eval() method:
df['Risk Rating'] = df['Risk Rating'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x) if pd.notna(x) else [])

After that, you can apply a function to the df['Risk Rating'] column to remove the NaNs:
def remove_nan_from_list(lst):
    return [item for item in lst if item != 'nan' and pd.notna(item)]

df['Risk Rating'] = df['Risk Rating'].apply(remove_nan_from_list)

Finally, you can count the values of each list using the following:
df['Non-NaN Count'] = df['Risk Rating'].apply(len)

Again, the previous approach will only work if the sample data can be modified appropriately.
